# Using Polly to retry after HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, rest-client, polly

I am making a call to external API and I want to retry for some of the specific responses (like **BadGateway, Unauthorized, ServiceUnavailable**).
After 2nd retry, it says

> Task canceled ("A task was canceled.")

Why? I'm trying to use `Polly` with the following code:

```
try
{
    await Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => _reTryHttpStatusCodes.Contains(r.StatusCode))
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)
        })
        .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            responseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            return responseMessage;
        }
        );
    return null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (IsTransientException(ex))
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException("Exception Occured", ex);
    }
    throw;
}
```

```
private readonly HttpStatusCode[] _reTryHttpStatusCodes =
    new[]
    {
        HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
        HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout,
        HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
        HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
        HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
    };
```

Comment: https://cm.engineering/transient-timeouts-and-the-retry-rabbit-hole-net-4-5-f406cebbf194 may be of interest.

Comment: +1. `HttpClient` is known to throw `TaskCanceledException` for the timeout. Similar article: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/ . If using ASPNET Core 2.1, consider using [`HttpClientFactory` with in-built support for configuring policies in `DelegatingHandler`s](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) and [guidance on timeouts](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#use-case-applying-timeouts)

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `cancellationToken` to the `ExecuteAsync` method? Also are you aware of the fact the `HttpRequestMessage`s are not reusable? You should create a new instance for each and every retry attempt!